# Connect ram based PHP Sqlite and c++ Sqlite

Tags: php, c++, sqlite

hello I have php program that need to communicate with c++ program 
this 2 programs are use ram based SQLite, this is possible to share this 2 SQLite database between the programs ? if so how ?

Comment: Not directly, I guess you'd have to write a frontend server in either language to server the other. Maybe consider using another database (server based) altogether.

Answer (score -1):

There is PouchDB in JS for browsers or InMemory SQL supported DBs for servers. But you can also try this https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html for in memory SQLite. Never seen how stable or performant it is. Do the read the docs of sharing. Check 'In-memory Databases And Shared Cache' if there are two apps using one shared SQLiteDB.